# Отображение сигнала в зависимости от времени суток

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как сделать так: утром лампочка горит, а ночью - нет, и что бы время бралось у пользователя?

Comment: Вот бы конкретики. )

Answer (score 5):

```
var date = new Date();
if( date.getHours() > 6 and date.getHours() < 22){
//горит
}else{
//не горит
}
```